# Is it possible to initiate a TFS build from one collection to another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, collections, build

I'm looking for a way to allow one build to kick off another build in a different collection. If this is possible, is there a way for it to wait until the build is complete before continuing?

Comment: Sure. What version are you using? Have you looked at the REST APIs?

Comment: @Daniel Mann I'm using TFS 2017

Comment: Okay. Did you look at the REST API documentation? You can easily write scripts to cover this scenario, and the APIs are pretty well-documented. If you have a problem with using the REST APIs, you can ask a question about that.

Comment: @KevinCraft Just add a `PowerShell` task as the **last** task in your build definition, then run the script in **Shayki Abramczyk's** answer below.

Comment: @KevinCraft Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Powershell script that triggers the other build:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $BuildDefinitionId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $CollectionUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $TeamProject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Credentials
)

try
{
    $apiVersion = "2.0"
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}" -f $Credentials)))
    $body = @{ definition = @{id = $BuildDefinitionId} }
    $requestUrl = "$CollectionUrl/$TeamProject/_apis/build/builds" + "?api-version=$apiVersion"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType application/json -Uri $requestUrl -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)
    return $response
}

catch
{
    Write-Host "Failed to trigger build {$BuildDefinitionId}, Exception: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
    return $null
}
```

}

Example for the parameters:

> -BuildDefinitionId "37" -CollectionUrl "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" -TeamProject "MyProject" -Credentials "domain\user:MyP@ssw0rd"

You can fine [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts) how to use Powershell task on TFS.